# How do I eliminate invasive creeping fig?

Tags: figs, invasive

I live in Central Florida, in a courtyard-type home.  Growing THROUGH my rear wall is a creeping fig [I believe] coming from the outside of my wall from a neighbor's home.  I have heard that nothing ordinary will kill this - I have tried Roundup, & others tell me they have tried many other products, to no avail.  The growth on my side is beginning to take over the entire wall, eating into the stucco covering the wall, & the roots have shifted the wall off its base on my next-door neighbor's home.  We are desperate to get rid of this before we are forced to have our sides of the wall reconstructed!  Appealing to our back neighbor is useless, as she thinks it's just great!!  Please, can anyone help??

Comment: Pictures please !

Comment: Yes, clear photos, please, showing the base near the roots, a good closeup of a single leaf and then from 12-18 inches away, a photo of the plant itself. We can't go by a common name as often multiple plants share the same common name but are very different plants.